# regex to remove a particular query parameter

Tags: regex

We had a version of our website which added a lang query parameter to the end of any URL. It didn't last long as it created lots of duplicate pages... but they still exist in google. I'd like to do a redirect to basically remove ANY of the references.

An example is `https://www.example.com/?lang=au`

I am using a redirection plugin (wordpress) which supports regex, however I am having trouble with the formatting. It's removing the "Lang" part, but nothing else.

```
/(.*)\/?lang=*
```

That should then redirect to

```
https://www.example.com/$1
```

So any form eg: `example.com/sub-page/something-else/?lang=au` would redirect back to `example.com/sub-page/something-else/` (minus the lang param).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: try `/(.*)\/?lang=.*`

Comment: Try with following /(.*)\/?lang=([^]*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the regex you should use:

```
\/(.*)\/\?lang=.*
```

Basically you were using `=*` at the end of yours which means: ***Matches between zero and unlimited times the `=` character*** and that wasn't be able to match anything after `=`.

Using `lang=.*` means:

- `lang=` matches the characters lang= literally (case sensitive)
- `.*` matches any character (except for line terminators)

Comment: Works nicely thank you - it does seem to leave a ? behind though - is there any way to remove that too? Might get complicated though if there are other parameters? (though I don't think they are used on the site so it might not be an issue)

Comment: Edited the regex on my answer, give it a try! :) I replaced `?` with `\?` since it needs an escape to match the character literally.

Comment: Let me know if you need any help on handling other parameters, we will try to find a solution

Comment: Worked fantastically. thank you for the answer - and also the explanation :)